# How to insert a large number of list entries into sqlite statements

Tags: python, list, sqlite, apsw

Ok, I am using apsw with sqlite, and have a large list of entries.Each entry contains a new row to be inserted. The number of entries is sometimes 20, sometimes 21. Since apsw supports multiple sql statements in curser.execute(), I was wondering if there would be a less confusing way of inserting all my list entries into the database than just doing something like

```
for entry in foo:
    cursor.execute(INSERT OR UPDATE INTO database.main ("{0}".format(entry))
```

I want to do it in all one thread because sqlite auto-commits to the database each time the execute finishes. Is there an easier, more efficient, and less confusing way?

Answer (score 1):

apsw cursors have an [executemany method](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/cursor.html#apsw.Cursor.executemany):

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT OR UPDATE INTO database.main values (?)',foo)
```